# Describing someone who seeks to broaden their knowledge in multiple areas

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

*Polymath* seems to refer to someone who **has** a vast knowledge from multiple areas.

So, what would be a word to describe someone who **seeks** to broaden their experience and knowledge in multiple areas? Namely through hobbies, entertainment and traveling.

Comment: A person with many interests. Someone into everything (using hyperbole).

Comment: An *aspiring polymath*?

Comment: An autodidact? Don

Comment: Hum... Above all, a word that describes someone who has a **multitude** of interests. I guess someone curious who enjoys learning about new things, but with a focus on multiple areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone *generally and generically* seeking experiences from "multiple areas" is no doubt

[**inquisitive**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inquisitive)

> **1** Having or showing an interest in learning things; curious.

And someone *specifically* seeking new experiences from "from entertainment, hobbies and traveling," is essentially a

[**fan**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fan)

> A person who has a strong interest in or admiration for a particular
>   person or thing.

---

Interestingly enough, ["inquisitive" can also be used as a noun](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inquisitive).

Comment: The first is an adjective; I think OP is rather looking for a noun. This is because he asked for a single word to describe someone who seeks to broaden his knowledge in various fields. He also provided another noun to show what he is looking for. "Fan", as is stated in the very definition above, is unsuitable due to the restriction to "a particular thing"

Comment: @Sprottenwels _Inquisitive_ can also be used predicatively, like a noun: _He is inquisitive_. There you have your "single word." Before downvoting, please be more inquisitive about things.